# Partition by Range ERROR 1491 (HY000): The PARTITION function returns the wrong type

Tags: mysql, mariadb, partition

I am trying to partition a table by range. The column is type float. I know partitions do not work with float so I thought using a FLOOR() function would allow it to work see code below

```
 ALTER TABLE tester_full
    -> PARTITION BY RANGE (FLOOR(Alt))
    -> (
    -> PARTITION p200 VALUES LESS THAN (FLOOR(300.0)),
    -> PARTITION p300 VALUES LESS THAN (FLOOR(400.0))
    -> );
```

However when I run this I get the following error ERROR 1491 (HY000): The PARTITION function returns the wrong type
Can someone show me how to partition a column that has type float or what this error means?

Comment: FLOOR with floating-point argument returns rounded but floating-point value. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor - "For exact-value numeric arguments, the return value has an exact-value numeric type. For string or floating-point arguments, the return value has a floating-point type." Use CAST to INTEGER.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
 ALTER TABLE tester_full
    -> PARTITION BY RANGE (CAST(Alt AS UNSIGNED INTEGER))
    -> (
    -> .....
    -> PARTITION p200 VALUES LESS THAN (300),
    -> PARTITION p300 VALUES LESS THAN (400),
    -> .....
    -> PARTITION pMAX VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
    -> );
```